# PHP5 - Post not working in some scenarios

Tags: php

We migrated our version from php 5.2.x to 5.3.x recently.

We got a dynamic from loaded from xml doc which was working fine in 5.2.x.

Now after migration ,if dynamic form has few controls all the controls are posting on submit,but if there are many controls on the form all the controls are not being posted on submit.

Changed the php ini settings on server for post max time and max upload size to 250M but still no luck.

Please share  your suggestions

Comment: What form? What controls? What errors do you have? How do you know it doesn't work? Can you show us some code? Error logs?

Comment: Math,  i have  textboxes and selectboxes,checkboxes which loads dynamically from xml doc. When i submit the form if there are many controls the controls doesnot post    and i get blank values from few controls. If there are few controls i dont have any  problem

Answer (score 5):

If you have more than 1000 inputs you will need to update the [max_input_vars](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars) directive in your php.ini. This was introduced in PHP 5.3.9 and would explain why it worked in 5.2 but is not working for you in 5.3.

Answer (score 1):

How huge is your form? There was an DOS exploit in older versions of PHP, that made it necessary to limit the number of variables in a POST request.

You can set the value for [`max_input_vars`](http://php.net/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars) in `php.ini`.

Comment: i changed the max_input_vars to 10000 but still no luck @knitti

Comment: @lakshmikanth: And you have restarted your apache process, right?

Comment: @knitti yes i did ,these below is the confi file

Comment: always_populate_raw_post_data Off Off
log_errors_max_len 1024 1024
max_execution_time 500 500
max_file_uploads 20 20
max_input_nesting_level 64 64
max_input_time 500 500
max_input_vars 10000 10000
memory_limit -1 -1
output_buffering 4096 4096
post_max_size 250M 250M
realpath_cache_size 16K 16K
realpath_cache_ttl 120 120
register_globals Off Off
upload_max_filesize 250M 250M

Comment: thanks to every one,i finally fixed the problem,the memory limit was set to -1 ,i changed it to 128M it worked like a charm,nay ways thanks once again